Animating a cluster column and line chart with matplotlib
I am trying to make an animated chart that updates frame by frame to have the end result has two columns for each x-axis entry (which does vary between years or years and Q, but either way are strings) and a line.
I have two dataframes, which I read helps in this instance.
df

{'GDP': {'2013Q1': 6.2, '2013Q2': 6.1, '2013Q3': 6.63, '2013Q4': 6.63, '2014Q1': 5.29, '2014Q2': 5.29, '2014Q3': 5.29, '2014Q4': 5.29, '2015Q1': 3.88, '2015Q2': 3.88, '2015Q3': 3.88, '2015Q4': 3.88, '2016Q1': 1.01, '2016Q2': 1.01, '2016Q3': 1.01, '2016Q4': 1.01}, 'GDP, nominal’: {'2013Q1': -1.78, '2013Q2': -1.72, '2013Q3': -1.72, '2013Q4': -1.72, '2014Q1': 2.9, '2014Q2': 2.46, '2014Q3': -2.46, '2014Q4': 2.44, '2015Q1': 5.44, '2015Q2': 5.46, '2015Q3': 5.46, '2015Q4': 5.46, '2016Q1': 3.87, '2016Q2': 3.17, '2016Q3': 3.87, '2016Q4': 3.88}}

and df_line
{'GDP, nominal US$': {'2013Q1': -0.42, '2013Q2': 1.69, '2013Q3': 3.86, '2013Q4': 5.12, '2014Q1': 6.82, '2014Q2': 3.9, '2014Q3': 1.97, '2014Q4': 2.69, '2015Q1': 3.22, '2015Q2': 5.59, '2015Q3': 8.33, '2015Q4': 8.9, '2016Q1': 3.13, '2016Q2': 1.43, '2016Q3': 0.45, '2016Q4': 1.94}}

I have made a line plot separately and a cluster column chart separately which works just fine.
I tried the following
#Because dates are strings did this
dates_vals = list(df.index)
date_indices = np.arange(len(dates_vals))
x = np.arange(len(df))  # Numeric x-axis for plotting
X_2 = np.arange(len(df_line))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))

n_columns = len(df.columns) #as it is df I want to be columns 
# Width of a single bar
bar_width = 0.9 / n_columns

# Create bar containers
bars = []
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    bar = ax.bar(x + i * bar_width, [0] * len(df), bar_width, label=col)
    bars.append(bar)

# Create the line plot with initial data set to NaNs to hide it initially
line, = ax.plot(X_2, [np.nan]*len(df_line), color="goldenrod", label=df_line.columns[0])


# Initialize function
def init():
    for bar in bars:
        for rect in bar:
            rect.set_height(0)
    line.set_ydata([np.nan]*len(df_line))  # Hide the line initially
    return [rect for bar in bars for rect in bar] + [line]

# Animate function
def animate(i):
    for j, bar in enumerate(bars):
        for k, rect in enumerate(bar):
            if k <= i:
                rect.set_height(df.iloc[k, j])
            else:
                rect.set_height(0)
    
    # Update the line data to show up to the current frame
    line.set_ydata(df_line.iloc[:i + 1].values.ravel())
    
    return [rect for bar in bars for rect in bar] + [line]


# Create the animation
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=len(df), interval=50, blit=True, repeat=False
)




Now this does work, but what it does is display a solid line across all of the X-axis from the start, and the two bars for the first x-axis entry. Then nothing happens for a while, until it jumps to the final frame which is how the chart should look.
Apologies if I have overseen something obvious, new to animating charts.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Managed to get it working with the following code:
# Create bar containers
bars = []
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    bar = ax.bar(x + i * bar_width, [0] * len(df), bar_width, label=col, color=Custom_Colours[i])
    bars.append(bar)

# Create the line plot with initial data set to NaNs to hide it initially
line, = ax.plot(x, [np.nan]*len(df_line), color="goldenrod", label=df_line.columns[0])


# Initialize function
def init():
    for bar in bars:
        for rect in bar:
            rect.set_height(0)
    line.set_ydata([np.nan] * len(df_line))  # Hide the line initially
    return [rect for bar in bars for rect in bar] + [line]

# Animate function
def animate(i):
    for j, bar in enumerate(bars):
        for k, rect in enumerate(bar):
            if k <= i:
                rect.set_height(df.iloc[k, j])
            else:
                rect.set_height(0)
    
    # Update the line data to show up to the current frame
    line.set_ydata(df_line.iloc[:i + 1])
    line.set_xdata(x[:i + 1])
    
    return [rect for bar in bars for rect in bar] + [line]

The issue was I hadn't set the x data:
    line.set_xdata(x[:i + 1])

